# Is there are way to step through every line of code in Visual Studio 2008 without setting a breakpoint?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging

I have downloaded a sample mvc application which has a fair bit of code and quite complex. in order to understand the code i want to step through all of the code line by line as i complete basic functions via the gui. problem is i am not always sure which line the code executes from so i cannot always set a breakpoint.

is there a way to view all code line by line as it executes, in visual studio 2008, without setting a breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to try is to add a few breakpoints to specific functions that you know will execute when you invoke certain GUI operations.

Then, examine the call stack when breaking in the debugger to see if there are any common library methods which are common to each of the call stacks (i.e. at the lower-end of the call stack).

Then perhaps you could add a breakpoint in the library method to catch all GUI operations.

Comment: I have a mvc4 project that runs application_start just fine but then dies. I would kill for a way to break on first line of code after that. problem is... huge project. I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it without at least one breakpoint.
Set a breakpoint on the first line of code.

You can then `step over` or `step into` every line there after.

**Update:**
Okay, RE your comments: Code executes in an inorder line by line fashion. The only time I have seen it execute "out of order" is with Xcode when certain compiler optimisations were activated. The tricky part was that the code was still executing in order, but the optimisations screwed up the debugger, making it *look like* it wasn't executing in order.

I would say look into Visual Studio's project settings and make sure you haven't played around with any strange compiler optimisations. What you are explaining should not happen otherwise.

Comment: ah but there is the problem... each function i test potentially executes from a different start point and i don't always know where that is.

Comment: they execute from a different start point? can you clarify that in your question please. Code should execute in line by line in order. Your comment doesnt make sense

Comment: hi brock. not sure i am missing something but i thought i had. "problem is i am not always sure which line the code executes from so i cannot always set a breakpoint". i am newish to programming so my basic assumptions may not be right.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand it correctly, but you can press F10 after the first line (with a break point) is reached and **step trough** every coming line in order of execution. Edit: and F11 "Steps into".

Comment: hi. problem is i need to set a breakpoint for this to work. i want to review each line of code executed without having to set a breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

Use F10 or F11 to start the project.

Comment: hi. problem is i need to set a breakpoint for this to work. i want to review each line of code executed without having to set a breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps add a line calling [System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) method in the application start event?

Answer (score 0):

It is too late to answer this question. But, any way just in case, if someone is still looking for it. Try following options for MVC project.

- Check in the `global.asax` file for the `RegisterRoutes` function. And put the break point on  all the actions used in the `MapRoute` methods.
- If it has `security` enabled, chances are it'll go to the `AccountController`'s `LogOn` method.
- Or run the project by pressing `F5` and check the URL in the browser.

One of these options should help.